# Rename computer and add join domain powershell script

Tags: powershell, join

I am trying to rename a machine and add it to the domain with 1 restart from WORKGROUP (after the machine gets renamed and joined domain). I tried the code below but it's giving me an error:

```
$bios = (Get-WmiObject Win32_Bios).SerialNumber
$name = $bios
Rename-Computer -NewName "$name"
$domain = "DOMAINNAME"
$username = "USERNAME"
$password = "PASSWORD" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username,$password)
Add-Computer -DomainName $domain -Credential $credential -NewName $name
Read-Host "The computer will restart in 5..."
shutdown /r /t 5
```

The error I'm receiving is the account already exist. It does join the domain but not the "Renamed" name that I want.

Comment: doesn't `Rename-Computer` usually require a restart to make the name change? this `-Restart [<SwitchParameter>] Indicates that this cmdlet restarts the computer that was renamed. A restart is often required to make the change effective.` seems to indicate that you should add a `-Restart` to the parameter list.

Comment: It should work without restart. I can rename and join the machine using system properties manually without restart. The only restart I do is when the machine joins the domain.

Comment: thank you for the feedback! still, ReadingTheFriendlyManual indicates it is "sometimes needed" ... have you tried it?

Comment: I did try it. It joins domain but the name changed didn't work. It joined the domain using the default name, disregarding the "renamed" name.

Comment: i am beyond my depth now. i will go back to lurking & hope someone knowledgeable shows up with an answer. good luck! [*grin*]

Comment: i found this over at r/powershell >> Rename computer and join to domain : PowerShell — https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/93efp4/rename_computer_and_join_to_domain/ ///// it says [1] `Rename-Computer` will fail in your situation. [2] use `Add-Computer` with `-NewName` &  `-Restart` to do what you need done.

Comment: Do you mean to remove the Rename-Computer part but still use Add-Computer -DomainName $domain -Credential $credential -NewName $name?

Comment: I think I tried this before. Does it matter if the computer object has been created already? The way we do it is we create the computer object first then join it to the domain.

Comment: from that thread, the problem with `Rename-Computer` in your situation is that the OLD name was already in AD - and that seems to match your error.

Comment: I tried taking out the Rename-Computer and just add the -NewName in the Add-Computer command. Also tried passing the $name as $bios but no luck. The machine joins the domain but not the NewName...

Comment: Pass serial number directly to $name instead of $bios. `$name = (Get-WmiObject Win32_Bios).SerialNumber` Run `Rename-Computer -NewName "$name" -Force` and see if your computer is actually getting renamed. I added `-Force` to the cmdlet. Also why are you giving `-NewName` again while joining to domain? You need to remove that. Use `Add-Computer -DomainName $domain -Credential $credential`

Comment: I will try that right now.

Comment: I did what you said. This is what happened: The rename-computer works. I put a pause in the script after the Rename-Computer to check if it works which it did. The Add-Computer $DomainName $domain -Credential $credential also works but after a restart, the machine reverted back to the default name and not the NewName...

Answer (score 3):

This is how it has to be done.

```
Rename-Computer -NewName newserver -Force
Add-Computer -DomainName example.ne -Credential $credential -NewName newserver -Options JoinWithNewName
```

You could better read the full documentation of `Add-Computer` cmdelt. `Get-Help Add-Computer -Online`

Comment: Hi Prasoon! I used this one: Rename-Computer -NewName $name Add-Computer -DomainName $domain -Credential $credential -options JoinWithNewName -Force -restart - It is now working!